# ¿Cómo comparar el nombre de un archivo con un texto usando * en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un directorio con muchos archivos del tipo:
XXXCC003.SCH
donde me interesa comparar las "CC" del nombre de cada archivo para luego mover ese archivo a un directorio con todos los que tengan el mismo valor en CC.

para lo anterior uso el siguiente código

```
import shutil, os
from glob import glob

if os.path.exists("29-a&e"):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "29-a&e"')
if os.path.exists("22-animalPlanet"):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "22-animalPlanet"')
if os.path.exists("07-axn"):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "07-axn"')
if os.path.exists("06-discovery"):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "06-discovery"')
if os.path.exists("41-discoveryInvestigation"):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "41-discoveryInvestigation"')
if os.path.exists('09-history'):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "09-history"')
if os.path.exists('50-home&health'):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "50-home&health"')
if os.path.exists("08-sony"):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "08-sony"')
if os.path.exists('43-tlc'):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "43-tlc"')
if os.path.exists("05-warner"):
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir "05-warner"')

print('Clasificando archivos')
files = glob('*.SCH')
for file in files:
    if file == '*29003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "29-a&e")
    elif  file == '*22003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "22-animalPlanet&e")
    elif  file == '*07003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "07-axn")
    elif  file == '*06003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "06-discovery")
    elif  file == '*41003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "41-discoveryInvestigation")
    elif  file == '*09003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "09-history")
    elif  file == '*50003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "50-home&health")
    elif  file == '*08003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "08-sony")
    elif  file == '*43003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "43-tlc")
    elif  file == '*05003.SCH':
        shutil.move(file, "05-warner")
```

probablemente exista una forma más eficiente de hacerlo todo (recien estoy aprendiendo).

Mi problema viene cuando comparo el nombre del archivo para clasificarlo. file == '*29003.SCH' nunca devuelve true, ni los demás if. Pensaba que al usar * funcionaría como "comodín", pero veo que no... alguna idea de cómo hacerlo???

Comment: Puede que te interese aprender sobre expresiones regulares. Son similares a los comodines pero más potentes. En una expresión regular, el comodín se escribe como `.*` (punto asterisco).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes simplificar mucho el código usando dos herramientas de Python

- Las expresiones regulares
- Un diccionario de configuración del proceso

Una prueba inicial de concepto podría ser esta:

```
import re

# Creación del diccionario de configuración del proceso
cfg_list = [("^.*29003\.SCH$","29-a&e"),
            ("^.*22003\.SCH$", "22-animalPlanet&e")
]

cfg_dict = dict(cfg_list)

# Creación de carpetas
for k, v in cfg_dict.items():
  print("Mkdir de la carpeta {0}".format(v))

# Mover los archivos
archivos = ["file1_29003.SCH", "file2_29003.SCH", "file3_222003.SCH"]

for f in archivos:
  for k, v in cfg_dict.items():
    if re.match(k,f):
      print("Mover el archivo {0} a la carpeta {1}".format(f,v))
```

La salida:

```
Mkdir de la carpeta 29-a&e
Mkdir de la carpeta 22-animalPlanet&e
Mover el archivo file1_29003.SCH a la carpeta 29-a&e
Mover el archivo file2_29003.SCH a la carpeta 29-a&e
Mover el archivo file3_222003.SCH a la carpeta 22-animalPlanet&e
```

#### Detalles

- Verás que simplifiqué tu ejemplo a dos casos nomas, pero no debería ser complicado completar todos los que ya tienes en la lista que llamé `cfg_list`. Notarás también que la lista se construye con tuplas de dos valores: el primero es un patrón de búsqueda y el segundo es el nombre de la carpeta
- También armé un ejemplo de casos de archivos, en tu caso simplemente recorrerías la lista que te entrega `glob('*.SCH')`tal cual lo estás haciendo
- En teoría simplemente deberías modificar los `print` de mi ejemplo con las operaciones reales, el `mkdir` y  el `move`.
- La expresión regular es un tema bastante amplio que te recomiendo que investigues por que resulta muy útil. En este caso estamos definiendo un patrón como `"^.*29003\.SCH$"`, que básicamente significa:

  - `^` match desde el primer caracter de la cadena
  - `.*` cualquier caracter
  - `29003` La cadena `29003`
  - `\.` un punto
  - `SCH` La cadena `SCH` y que además:
  - `$` se el último conjunto de caracteres del texto
- La lista, la pasamos a un diccionario ya que es una estructura mucho más rápida para acceder a cada elemento, los diccionarios tienen elementos del tipo `clave: valor`.

  - Para crear las carpetas, simplemente recorremos todos los `valores` del diccionario.
  - Para hacer el matching del archivo con el patrón y determinar la carpeta a mover, hacemos algo parecido, pero debemos verificar cada patrón con cada archivo: `if re.match(k,f):`, es decir el matching de hace por la clave y en `v` tengo el valor o el nombre de la carpeta que corresponde a dicha clave.

Comment: muchas gracias, con tu explicación me quedó todo super claro

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas es `fnmatch`

Prueba con:

```
import fnmatch
import os

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*29003.SCH'): 
  print "te encontré "
```